# Moq Verify not matching on invocation

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, moq

Before starting, I have used Moq to mock things in unit tests for years. This should be a simple mock verify, but for whatever reason moq is not matching the invocation on the Mock when it occurs. I've manually tested, it is hit. I've debugged the test and compared actual vs. expected values (they match), I've scoured SO and its multitudes of people doing blatantly wrong things and I cannot figure out why this isn't working. Help appreciated.

The unit test is a very simple test of checking if `BulkInsert` is called at the end of a `void` returning function. Sample code:

Code:

```
public interface IDependencyService
{
    void BulkInsert(IList<T> items);
}

public class MyServiceClass
{
    private readonly IDependencyService _service;

    /* ctor and all that jazz */

    public void Run()
    {
        /* do things to the data */
        
        _service.BulkInsert(items); // where items is an IList<T>
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class ServiceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void ServiceRun_Calls_DependencyBulkInsert()
    {
        var dependencyMock = new Mock<IDependencyService>();
        List<T> expected = /* somehow build expected values */
        dependencyMock
            .Setup(mock => mock.BulkInsert(It.IsAny<IList<T>>()));
        var sut = new MyServiceClass(dependencyMock.Object);
        sut.Run();

        dependencyMock.Verify(mock => mock.BulkInsert(expected), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: mock => mock.BulkInsert([ThresholdCheck])
Performed invocations:

   Mock<IThresholdCheckHandler:1> (mock):

      IThresholdCheckHandler.GetQueuedChecks()
      IThresholdCheckHandler.BulkInsert([ThresholdCheck])
```

If I change `expected` to `It.IsAny<T>()` in the Verify call, test passes. This leads me to believe that maybe somehow the objects passed from expected are somehow different from the objects generated when running the program. However as stated I've went through with the debugger and manually compared every value in the actual list to the expected list of values in the test and they are *exactly* the same.

This then leads me to believe that I'm just a stupid bipedal monkey clicking at a keyboard and that the problem is right in front of me and I'm just not seeing it. Any help or set of eyes is appreciated.

Comment: Unless expected is the actual list (reference) that was passed into the mocked member then the behavior you described is by design.

Comment: Well, List<T> is equal only to itself, even if your two lists have same elements, 'Equals' for them will return false. Keep list that is passed to mocked method using Callback and then compare it to expected.via something like CollectionAssert.IsEqual

Comment: Ah ok I didnt think that Verify operated off references, that's very annoying. I dont really understand why they would operate on references rather than the equality of the object. Thanks for the heads up, I will look into Callback

Answer (score 1):

As per NKosi's comment, `Verify` operates via. reference when using reference types. I was confused as I'd used `Verify` in the past for simple things like ints and strings but was unaware of that quirk. One would assume with Verify that it would check the equivalency of actual vs. expected, but no.

Regardless then, as per Quercus's comment I adjusted my test to this in order to continue with my day:

```
public class ServiceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void ServiceRun_Calls_DependencyBulkInsert()
    {
        var dependencyMock = new Mock<IDependencyService>();
        List<T> actual = new List<T>();
        List<T> expected = /* somehow build expected values */
        dependencyMock
            .Setup(mock => mock.BulkInsert(It.IsAny<IList<T>>()))
            .Callback<List<T>>(l => actual = l);
        var sut = new MyServiceClass(dependencyMock.Object);
        
        sut.Run();

        actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
    }
}
```

and this solution works for me. thanks to you both for helping me realize my mistake.

Comment: Since you are using fluent assertions you can also do `It.Is<IList<T>>(actual => actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected))` in your original example